# Shopware 6 Admin API - How to delete/update entites by custom route

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I'm working on a custom entity which I want to manage via the sw6 admin api.

Therefore I want to be able to write entities by using post-, get- and delete-requests.

SW 6 automatically generates the desired routes for me. But I want to delete/update a specific entity and sw6 only generates routes with the primary key (e.g. /api/entity/{id}). For my use case I need to delete entities by a route with a specific field though.

I tried to achieve that by making my field a primary key. That doesn't work though, because sw6 expects an uuid/binary value and I specifically need a string value.

Is there any way to define a custom route (e.g. /api/entity/{myfield}) and write a custom controller or a way to use a string field as primary key?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can find your answer here by overwriting the existing routes with your custom [Override - existing route](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/store-api/override-existing-route).

Comment: Remark: That article is about the store-API, but it might work for the admin-API similarly.